# Holography with object and reference waves with a slightly different wavelength

Tags: optics, hologram

Recently I've been looking into holography, where one interferes the object wave with a reference wave and encodes their combined intensity on a transparency, so that if one then re illuminates the transparency with the same reference wave we get (in addition to three other waves) the object wave again, not just intensity but also phase.

Now, in my book it is stressed that one needs high coherence, monochromatic light to do this. But it isn't clear to me what goes wrong when the object and the reference wave have slightly different wavelengths. I suppose that this will influence their interference pattern on the transparency, but I find it hard to put it into equations.

This is how far I get myself. We take a reference wave $U_r$ and an object wave $U_o$ (propagation in z-direction) and record their intensity pattern on the transparancy $t(x,y)$

$t(x,y) = |U_r+U_o|^2 = |U_r|^2+|U_o|^2 + U^*_rU_o + U_rU^*_o$.

Lets then reshine our reference wave, and we get

$U' = tU_r \propto U_rI_r + U_rI_0 + I_r U_0 + U_r^2 U_0^*$

where I have used $|U|^2 = I$.

So we have the four waves I mentioned before. But how do I now identify the problem of introducing slightly different wavelengths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create the original hologram by creating an interference pattern that is then recorded on the holographic film. If you use two light sources with different wavelengths they will not produce a static interference pattern but one that strobes at a frequency equal to the difference between the frequencies of the two light sources you're using. Unless you manage to use an exposure time short relative to the period of the strobing your film will contain a smeared out blur not an interference pattern.

For more on this see my answer to [Can light waves cause beats?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56144/can-light-waves-cause-beats).

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, the issue is not in different wavelengths, but in different frequencies. (The first case would still allow you, e.g., to record holograms happily from two noncollinear beams in a hypothetical anisotropic photographic emulsion.)

The difference of frequencies, however, is nothing but a steadily growing phase difference between both beams. This would result in the interference maxima and minima of $U_r U_o^*$ or $U_r^* U_o$ constantly shifting in space, eventually smearing out the fine holographic patterns that are to be recorded.

Once the hologram is made, you can however approximately recover the object wave even with a slightly different frequency than the original reference wave had. The amount of distortion or efficiency drop depends on the type of the hologram.